# How do i get a number data and date data from parse and put it to UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I want to retrieve **createdAt** and **price** from parse database and the datatypes for both are **Number** and **NSDate**. After I retrieved it I want to pass to UILabel which is **date** and **price** respectively. The problem right now is that whenever I tried to run the simulator, both of the UILabel data don't show up while string data type does show up.

My current code

```
if let createdAt = object?["createdAt"] as? String {
            cell.date.text = createdAt
        }


if let priceTitle = object?["price"] as? String {
            cell.price.text = priceTitle
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure? "createdAt" is a special value in Parse and is a `NSDate`.

Comment: Yeah it is in date but how do I convert it to String? can you answer the question so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

For Date, use NSDateFormatter.stringFromDate method so your code should be:

```
if let createdAt = object?["createdAt"] as? NSDate {
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  var theDateFormat = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
  dateFormatter.dateStyle = theDateFormat
  cell.date.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(createdAt) 
}
```

Comment: I used your code but I got "Use of undeclared type "Date", what is the problem?

Comment: Made a change: not Date but NSDate sorry :-)

Comment: I tried to println(cell.date.text) but nothing showed up

Comment: Are you passing thru the if ?

Answer (score 0):

`createdAt` is a special value in Parse. It is `PFObject`'s property and you access it with dot notation. So this is how you should proceed:

```
if let object = object as? PFObject {
    let date = object.createdAt
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm MMMM dd, yyyy"
    let dateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
    cell.date.text = dateStr
}
```

Comment: I tried to println but it doesn't show the  output. What is the problem?